# Apply effect to only one mesh in a three js scene

Tags: three.js, shader

Is there a way to include two meshes in a scene, one with some effects applied to it and one without.

For example, I would like to replicate this [colored lines example](http://threejs.org/examples/?q=lines#webgl_lines_colors) where one of the meshes has all shader the effects applied, while another has none of the shader effects applied (in this case the `THREE.BloomPass` effect).

Comment: You question is "Is there a way to include two meshes ..." and you post an example that does what you want so I dont understand the question.

Comment: I don't think the answer does what I want, because all the meshes have the `THREE.BloomPass` applied to them. It's actually applied to the whole scene I think.

Comment: I think you need to explain what you want a little bit better.

Comment: Ok I've tried to make it a little clearer, thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Multiple scenes or a maskPass- Both have disadvantages. A key concept: effects is a 2d pass over the output, utilizing 3d data, not a manipulation of 3d data. Problems occur as objects are changing position. For example, when using multiple scenes, objects may will be front of others incorrectly. When using a maskpass, parts of objects which occlude your mask will be  postprocessed with the target object. Interestingly, a glow pass per object was added to THREEx: https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex/tree/master/src/threex.glowscene and may help you understand a working technique.